# Extract from string latest substring with alpa character with or not other numbers on PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to normalize a data series and I find a problem in one of the fields.

From where I get the data, it is supposed that I should be normalized and return a string of no more than 14 characters, composed of two alpha characters and the rest numbers

But sometime between the 90 million items, there are some that may have one or two additional items that always start with an undetermined or serializable alpha character, and a number (or not)

Normalized values (AA + 000000000000)

```
EP0123456789   
ES123456
FR1234567890123
```

Incorrect values (AA + 00000000 + A) OR (AA + 00000000 + A0)

```
EP1025364758A 
FR1920393874B1 
CH172637488858A
CN727363525252W2
```

`A` -> Any Alpha
`0` ->  Any number (positive)

For extract normalized values (AA00000000 Code, A0 KindCode) I use a bit complish code. I think there're a best algorithm

```
$pat = 'FR1920393874B1';
if (preg_match("/[a-z]/i",substr($pat, -2))) {
   $fail = substr($pat, -2);
   if (preg_match('/[\A-Za-z]+/', $fail, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
      $kind = substr($fail,$match[0][1]);         // B1 
      $pat  = str_replace($kind,'',$pat);     // FR1920393874
   }
}
```

**So, I need to get 2 values out of an input string**:

1. The first two alpha chars and 1 or more digits after them
2. The rest of the string

So, for `FR1920393874B1`, I want to get `FR1920393874` and `B1` as separate values.

Comment: What is your question about? What are "normalized" values? Why are the "incorrect" values  incorrect? What are you going to do with incorrect values?

Comment: Try this `^\D+\d+(?!=\D)`

Comment: Well, if the problem is to grab two letters the start of the string and then any 1+ digits, use `preg_match('~^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d+~', $pat, $match)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry for my english. normalized is a string taht start with two characters, a has several numbers with max 14 length. Example on my post. Not normalized it's when fater some number has a one letter  or one letter plus a number... with same lenthg

Comment: Yes, but I do not think it is relevant unless you explain what  behavior you need for these strings. From your code, I can deduce you just need `preg_match('~^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d+~', $pat, $match)`. Am I right? But this is a guess until you confirm your real intention.

Comment: Update: `preg_match('/\D+\d+/', "FR1920393874B1", $match); echo $match[0];`

Comment: All two codes work, but it's other form over original ... on all cases  I need a bit code for extract $pat and verified if there're are extra $kind

Comment: Please explain: if your input is `FR1920393874B1`, what is the result you expect to get? If your input is `FR1920` what is the result you need to get? Hm, and check [`preg_match('~^([a-zA-Z]{2}\d+)(.*)~', $pat, $match)`](https://ideone.com/Epw8na).

Comment: oh.. yes.. @WiktorStribiżew your code it's the best piece. Work perfectly on little piece of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you need to actually split the codes from the rest of the string and get 2 values in the output.

Use a `^([a-zA-Z]{2}\d+)(.*)` pattern:

```
$pat = 'FR1920393874B1';
if (preg_match('~^([a-zA-Z]{2}\d+)(.*)~', $pat, $m)) {
    echo "Val: " . $m[1] . "\nKind: " . $m[2];
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Epw8na)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([a-zA-Z]{2}\d+)` - Capturing group 1 (`$m[1]`): 2 ASCII letters and then 1+ digits
- `(.*)` - Capturing group 2 (`$m[2]`): any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (the rest of the line)